# Is turiya the ultimate state?

Tags: yoga

Is turiya the ultimate state of pure consciousness void of senses, dreams, that is to say, are all siddhis such as ability to become light/float, divine, inner, cosmic visions, insights, automatically attained as a byproduct/side effect when one attains the turiya state? Or do they require mantra sadhana or meditation after attaining the turiya state?

Comment: Turiya, Turiyathitha. Spirituality begins when one reaches Turiya and beyond Turiya there are 2 more chakras outside physical body = 12 Angalas from Sahasra. One needs to go beyond that also. How Angalas are translated to English I dont know. Angala is measurement in Tamil!
So what we do until we reach Turiya = those are karmic impressions of this Loka. Our life functions two levels. = Earthly & spiritual. Eradicating earthly impressions is first stage and when one reaches Turiya, his spiritual journey begins!

Comment: There is also a 5th state called Turiyatita which is even beyond Turiya.

Comment: Is turiya attained when kundalini pierces through all Chakras?

Comment: The last state is Shivahood.

Comment: Are there rebirths after turiya state?